# FirebaseFirestore withConverter for nested collections

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following class

```
class Match {
   List<Subscription> subs
}
```

`Match` and `Subscription` are Firestore documents. A subscription collection is inside a match

```
/matches/<match_doc_id>/subscriptions/<sub_doc_id>
```

I am trying to use this code to get a typed document converted

```
 var _ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('matches').withConverter<Match>(
     fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Match.fromJson(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id),
     toFirestore: (match, _) => match.toJson(),
 );
```

However this doesn't work since `snapshot.data` contains only fields of the match document but not subcollections.

Is there a way to use typed collections with subcollections?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Reads from `matches` never return data from subcollections, so you should not need your subtype there. And once you read from the `Subscription` collection, you can pass the correct type for that collection.

Comment: I would like to have `subscription` list deserialized inside `Match` object

Comment: Ah got it. Note that even if you get the type in there, there's no way the Firestore SDK will auto-read the subscriptions when you read a match.

Comment: I see. What do you think is the best way to pack these two things in the same object?

Comment: What you're trying is not necessarily wrong, I just don't know if FlutterFire has a syntax to exclude your `List<Subscription> subs` from its (de)serialization. If it doesn't, the list will end up in the match instead of in the subcolleciton.

Comment: it is excluded in the `withConverter` logic above so I don't get it in the `Match` object